# Can the virtual function be found at runtime without calling?

Tags: c++, virtual

I have a base class `Base`, with many derived classes (eg. `Derived1`, `Derived2`). `Base` has a pure virtual function `fn`, which is called many times using a `Base` pointer. Every time the function is called, I need to do some extra logging and related stuff. In particular, I use `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION` in the derived-class functions to find out which function was called. Is there a way to know this information before calling the function, so that I do not have to rewrite the bookkeeping code in every derived function?

Edit: I wish to avoid writing `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in each derived function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
virtual void fn() = 0;
};

class Derived1:public Base {
public:
void fn() {
cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
}
};

class Derived2:public Base {
public:
void fn() {
cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    int choice =0;
    Base *ptr1 = nullptr;
    cout<<"Choose 0/1: "<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice == 0) {    
       ptr1 = new Derived1;
    }else {
       ptr1 = new Derived2;
    }

    //********CAN I WRITE SOMETHING HERE, TO GIVE THE SAME RESULT?
    ptr1->fn();
}
```

Comment: Can you post a small example of what you want to achieve, so we don't answer the "wrong" questions?

Comment: (I'm pretty sure, from the description of `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`, that it's just a wrapper for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or something similar)

Comment: Make the method non virtual, let it do the book keeping and calling the actual virtual function, methodImpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot be. C++ does not support this kind of introspection. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is all you're gonna get.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems you migth have a design issue. Have you considered using the [template method design patter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method)? The idea is to have your  base class implement the common functionality and through virtual functions implement the specifics in your derived classes.

Comment: The problem is, it's not common functionality right? The functionality I want is to see which derived function is called.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to implement the base pure virtual function and call it in each derived override. In the base one you increment a static counter. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base
{
    static size_t counter;
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
size_t Base::counter{0};

void Base::f() // IMPLEMENTATION, yes it's possible to implement a pure virtual function
{
    ++counter;
}

struct Derived1: Base
{
    void f() override
    {
        Base::f(); // increment the counter
        std::cout << "Derived1::f()\n";
    }
};

struct Derived2: Base
{
    void f() override
    {
        Base::f(); // increment the counter
        std::cout << "Derived2::f()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> pBase1{new Derived1};
    std::unique_ptr<Base> pBase2{new Derived2};

    pBase1->f();
    pBase1->f();

    pBase2->f();

    std::cout << Base::counter << std::endl; // outputs 3
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PNesnekK0DOeZSnn)

If I'm not wrong I believe this is an instance of the Template Method design pattern [mentioned by @LordDosias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35049062/3093378). There is no other intrinsic way of getting this information out from the language, as C++ does not have genuine runtime reflection capabilities.

Comment: I wouldn't call this the pure template method design pattern. But at the end of the day this is just semantics. In my opinion template method would be having Base::f() not be a pure virtual function, but an ordinary function which in turn calls private virtual method which are then implemented in the derived classes. But as I said whatever gets the job done :)

Comment: @LordDoskias Yes I believe it's a matter of semantics. I knew about this from Scott Meyers' Effective C++, in which he was mentioning the fact that the common bookkeeping can be achieved by implementing a pure virtual function (which at the time I had no idea one can do).

Comment: um.. The idea is to have bookkeeping code only once (it's not just simple printing the function name). This approach doesn't help with that, right?

Comment: @user2308211 Cannot you factor the bookkeeping code into `Base::f()`? If not, then you really have to do it manually in each derived override.

Comment: The bookkeeping code needs to know whether it's Derived1::f() or Derived2::f()

Comment: @user2308211 In this case the only thing that comes to my mind is to somehow pass a parameter to `Base::f()` which tells you which `DerivedX` you are calling, and based on that parameter process it in `Base::f()`. The language does not offer intrinsic support for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a ``DerivedType`` enum member, which identifies what the derived type is, I'll have to fall back to that I suppose.

Comment: I think you have a bigger design issue, because you essentially want your base class to know about each and every possible derive classes that you have. And this is not a good OOP design. Refactor your code so that you base doesn't care which derived is being called so long as it can just call a function which is overloaded in the derived class.

Comment: I see your point, but for me, all I need is a function name, so that I can do stuff like log the amount of time taken in executing the call, memory allocated in the call etc..

Answer (score 0):

Well, aside from wrapping your macro in another macro that is smaller/shorter/does more, there is nothing that will provide the name of a function for you.

```
   #define WHERE cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl
   ...
   void fn() {
      WHERE;
   }
```

This also means you can turn on/off the tracing trivially:

```
  #if TRACING
     #define WHERE cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl
  #else
     #define WHERE
  #endif
```

(You may want to wrap that in `do { ... } while(0)` in both sides to avoid problems if you were to put a `WHERE` inside an if, or some such, and still want it to work correctly when when it's "nothing")

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that, since C++ doesn't have auxiliary methods, you have to split the implementation of `fn` into a utility wrapper and the virtual function proper:

```
class Base {
protected:
  virtual void fn_impl() = 0;
public:
  void fn() { fn_impl(); }
};

class BaseWithLogging: public Base {
public:
  void fn(); {
    /* do logging */
    fn_impl();
  }
};
```

If you want the logs to capture the exact identity of the virtual (function name, file, line number, ...) which is actually, then there is no workaround for that; the boilerplate has to go into the function.

The crusty old preprocessor can be of help. E.g. simple-minded illustration:

```
#define LOG (cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl)
```

and then you just have

```
LOG;
```

at the beginning of the function.